# I use homebrew to install nginx, and how to add 3rd modules?

Tags: nginx, module, addition, homebrew

I brew install nginx on my mac, but I don't know where is the configure file, and I use 'brew install nginx --add-module=xxxx' to add modules is not working... please help!!!

Answer (score 15):

The **nginx-full** brew formula has a number of options that enables you to install 3rd party 
modules.

See the output of `brew info nginx-full`.

E.g. the [HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) can be installed with the command

```
brew install nginx-full --with-headers-more-module
```

Comment: now there is current console command:

`brew install homebrew/nginx/nginx-full --with-push-stream-module`

Answer (score 14):

At this time (April 2018) `nginx-full` is deprecated by default. To install 3rd party modules:

1. `brew tap denji/nginx`
2. `brew install nginx-full --with-nchan-module` (or [some other module](https://denji.github.io/homebrew-nginx/))

Comment: `--with-lua-module` does not work anymore: https://github.com/denji/homebrew-nginx/issues/407