# brew install 3rd party nginx modules on nginx to enable Headers More

Tags: nginx, http-headers, homebrew

I can't seem to figure out how to install the Headers More module for nginx when I've installed nginx using homebrew.

I've found [I use homebrew to install nginx, and how to add 3rd modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332633/i-use-homebrew-to-install-nginx-and-how-to-add-3rd-modules) but this doesn't actually recompile nginx with this module. It's just downloads the module.

I've found nginx-full but event with the --with-headers-more option I can't seem this module working.

I keep getting this error:

`nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "more_set_input_headers" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/....`

Answer (score 0):

I installed successfully using the following command

```
brew install nginx-full --with-headers-more-module
```

Make sure your brew formulas are up to date

```
brew update
```